# Bootstrap color selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

```
$('#colorselector').colorselector();

 <select id="colorselector" name="color[]">
    <option value="101" data-color="#00204E" selected="selected">Navy</option>
    <option value="102" data-color="#FF0000" >Red</option>
    <option value="103" data-color="#004F9E">Royal</option>
    <option value="104" data-color="#36454f">Carbon</option>
    <option value="105" data-color="#383428">Graphite</option>
</select>
```

> above code give me output as one color and then i need to click on that color to see more colors. is there any way by which we can directly see all colors???
> [Output should look like this..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scitQ.png)

[Currently i am getting somehting like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T06CT.png)

> For reference- I am using this code.
> http://bootstrap-colorselector.flaute.com/

Comment: I think the plugin you're using doesn't have option to show inline colors. You have to click a color to see the list. Please see this plugin it has inline display option too https://github.com/tkrotoff/jquery-simplecolorpicker

Comment: preview of above plugin: http://plnkr.co/edit/VVclW0?p=preview&preview

Comment: Thanks @maverickosama92